# Will __init__ be called automatically for every method call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
class linkedlist:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.head={'value':value,'next':None}
        self.tail=self.head
        self.length=1
    def append(self,value):
        self.newnode={'value':value,'next':None}
        self.tail['next']=self.newnode
        self.tail=self.newnode      
        self.length+=1
if __name__=='__main__':
    l=linkedlist(10)
    l.append(5)
    l.append(16)
```

The code is working fine but I have doubts about how `__init__` works. Will `__init__` be called for every function call? Its quite a bit confusing because I am changing the tail and the head value.

How does the main function works here?

Comment: No, `__init__` is called when you create the object, "init" stands for "initializer". It happens initially. So it gets called once here: `l=linkedlist(10)`

Comment: You can check by adding a print to `__init__` and seeing what happens.

Comment: `linkedlist` is the queue but you use an unnamed dictionary `{'value':value,'next':None}` for each of the nodes in the list. You created 1 queue (and called one `linkedlist.__init__`). Every time you append something you create a new dictionary and its `__init__` is called.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Then when i pass `l.append(16)` am updating the `tail` but how the `head` gets updated?

Comment: `self.head` doesn't get updated. On `.append(16)`.  But, you *do* mutate the object `self.head` is referring to when it happens to be referring to the same object as `self.tail` (when the list has one item in it)

Answer (score 0):

The main use of **init** function is for initialization. It is called when we make an object, at the same time all values mentioned in the function will be initialized and associate with the object. The best way to find out how the function is working or how the whole code is working sequentially, just try to add print function in it.